# A continue or break from a subshell inside a loop no longer works

Tags: bash

The following code works in bash on any number of Linux distros, including
CentOS 6.10 - 7.8 and Ubuntu 14.04 - 18.04.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Test for continue from subshell issue...
#
echo SHELL is $SHELL
for i in $(seq 5)
do
    (
    echo loop $i
    if [[ $i == 2 ]] ; then
        echo i = $i - continue
        continue
    fi

    if [[ $i == 4 ]] ; then
        echo i = $i - exit
        exit 1
    fi
    echo Loop $i subshell end
    )
    rc=$?
    echo Loop $i rc $rc
done
```

The output on all of those machines is:

```
SHELL is /bin/bash
loop 1
Loop 1 subshell end
Loop 1 rc 0
loop 2
i = 2 - continue
Loop 2 rc 0
loop 3
Loop 3 subshell end
Loop 3 rc 0
loop 4
i = 4 - exit
Loop 4 rc 1
loop 5
Loop 5 subshell end
Loop 5 rc 0
```

On a Ubuntu 20.04 machine:

```
SHELL is /bin/bash
loop 1
Loop 1 subshell end
Loop 1 rc 0
loop 2
i = 2 - continue
packages/tmp/looptest: line 14: continue: only meaningful in a `for', `while',
or `until' loop
Loop 2 subshell end
Loop 2 rc 0
loop 3
Loop 3 subshell end
Loop 3 rc 0
loop 4
i = 4 - exit
Loop 4 rc 1
loop 5
Loop 5 subshell end
Loop 5 rc 0
```

--
If I change the shebang to:   #!/bin/sh
the behavior is the same as the first example - except - on our machines, we
specifically link /bin/sh to bash:

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 May 12 22:04 /bin/sh -> /bin/bash
```

Which seems just... weird.

This behavior seems to have started after a recent update to Ubuntu 20.04.

I realize that the argument can be made the new behavior is more technically
correct, but using a subshell to isolate vars between loops can be very helpful
and the fact that this has worked until now is concerning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an old Ubuntu installation or an old bash, so i can't verify this. But this bugfix looks like a good explanation to me.

```
a. Fixed a bug that allowed subshells to "inherit" enclosing loops -- this
   is where POSIX says the subshell is not "enclosed" by the loop.
```

[Source (see line 813)](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES)

Edit: i don't have an explanation why "/bin/sh -> /bin/bash" would make a difference.

Comment: Yes - I think that might be it.   Not clear what "this" is in the 'this is where POSIX says the subshell is not "enclosed" by the loop.' but i expect that's where this is going.  

I can see where this might be more correct/consistent, but being able to isolate vars in a subshell and still "continue" out of the loop is a handy construct.   I've since gone through our code and converted any "continue"s inside a subshell, inside a loop - to "exit" from the subshell.

Thanks, Sheldon.

Comment: @JohnnyKlonaris i understand "this" as reference to "this feature" or "this aspect". Feel free to [accept the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) if this answered your question.